# ROS Answers SE migration: rosrun UWSim

Tags: ros, rosrun, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hy,
i'm trying to run UWSim but when I type rosrun UWSim UWSim it shows me this:

Warning: Failed to connect to host. Make sure 3D acceleration is enabled for this VM.

[ INFO] [1364229036.589787181]: pluginlib WARNING: PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS is deprecated, please use PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS instead. You can run the script 'plugin_macro_update' provided with pluginlib in your package source folder to automatically and recursively update legacy macros.

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

i'm following installing instructions and don't understand where is the problem

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59131/rosrun-uwsim/) by [Marija-123](https://answers.ros.org/users/4397/marija-123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you're running from within a virtual machine.  UWSim requires OpenGL and a fairly recent graphics card.  You'll need to make sure your Virtual Machine is set up to provide hardware-accelerated access to the graphics card.  Not all VM environments support this.  See the discussion [here](http://forum.openscenegraph.org/viewtopic.php?t=10657) for more details.  If you're using VirtualBox, see [these](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-video) instructions for how to configure Hardware Accelerated Graphics.

Similar errors are often produced when trying to run rviz from a remote X-server or in a Virtual Machine, if the 3D graphics aren't set up correctly.

You can try using `glxinfo` or `glxgears` to test and see if your 3D environment is working correctly.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3